# Add input numbers from textarea

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm a JavaScript newbie..
    Trying to add the numbers from INPUT TEXTAREA, but I'm just getting array as output..
    Can someone please rectify the mistake and give me solution..
    Thanks in advance..

```js
function arraynum() {
  var numbers = Array(document.getElementById("sumofnumbers").value);
  var sumresult = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  document.getElementById("sumresult").innerHTML = sumresult;
}
```

```html
<input onblur="arraynum()" type="textarea" id="sumofnumbers">
<p id="sumresult"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a separator between numbers and split based on separator, and than loop through values and get desired output,

Here i am using `,`as separator

```js
function arraynum() {
  var numbers = document.getElementById("sumofnumbers").value.split(',').filter(Boolean)
  
  var sumresult = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a+ (+b),0);
  document.getElementById("sumresult").innerHTML = sumresult;
}
```

```html
<input onblur="arraynum()" type="textarea" id="sumofnumbers">
<p id="sumresult"></p>
```

***Note:-*** the value from HTML is string, you need to type cast it to numbers to perform addition else it will perform string concatenation

Comment: Thank you so much
I got the desired output..
But I didn't understood the purpose of filter(Boolean)

Comment: @ShylendherReddy to remove `falsy` value, let say you have string such `1,,,2` so the split will return `[1,"", "",2]`

Comment: @ShylendherReddy always happy to help :), you can mark as correct answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamental issue is with the following line:

```
var numbers = Array(document.getElementById("sumofnumbers").value);
```

The [`Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) constructor doesn't convert your input into an array of characters, it instead just encases your input text in an array, for example: `Array("1,2,3")` gives `["1,2,3"]`, it does not give `["1", "2", "3"]` like you may think.

A simple way to split your input into an array of characters is by using the `JSON.parse()` method on a correctly formatted array. If you do this, then your array will be an array of numbers, not just an array of one single element (ie: your input string).

```js
function arraynum() {
  var numbers = JSON.parse("["+document.getElementById("sumofnumbers").value +"]");
  var sumresult = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  document.getElementById("sumresult").textContent = sumresult; // use .textContent instead of .innerHTML as `sumresult` is a text only result
}
```

```html
<input onblur="arraynum()" type="textarea" id="sumofnumbers">
<p id="sumresult"></p>
```

Comment: Hey NIck,The result is NaN

Comment: @ShylendherReddy Hi, for what input does it product `NaN`?

Comment: I entered 1,2,3 in the textarea and the output is NaN

Comment: You need to split on `,`, else `1,2,3` will result `["1",',","2",",","3"]`, `...` will split on each character

Comment: @ShylendherReddy Hi, I thought your input was `"123"`, I didn't realize it was comma separated. I've updated my code